# Factory method 'broker' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [ws]

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, activemq-classic

I am trying to configure websocket with activemq server but I am gettting the above error .I have already replaced the localhost wit 0.0.0.0 but it didn't work.Below is my code please have a look

```
@Bean
    public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
        final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
         // configure the broker
        broker.addConnector( "ws://localhost:61614" );
        broker.setPersistent(false);

        final ActiveMQTopic topic = new ActiveMQTopic( topicstring );
        broker.setDestinations( new ActiveMQDestination[] { topic }  );

        final ManagementContext managementContext = new ManagementContext();
        managementContext.setCreateConnector(true);
        broker.setManagementContext(managementContext);
        return broker;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This would likely occur because the dependency needed for the HTTP and WS based transports is not included on the broker's classpath.  You should ensure that the broker is being created with the 'activemq-http' module listed in your dependencies such as a maven pom file or IDE setting.